# Use buttons as form checkboxes and associate their value with data in a textbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, hash

In my Rails 3.2 I have a form which asks users what kinds of odd jobs they're good at. Each category has a button that, when pressed, reveals a text box in which the user can provide a self-endorsement.

I everything pretty much set up on the front end but am unsure about how to move forward with storing the data. My questions are:

1) Is it possible to make the button act as a checkbox and then save the clicked buttons and their corresponding text data as hash key-values in a single "endorsements" attribute of the user model, with the category from the clicked button being the key and the text being the value?

2) If not (1), what would be the best way to store the data? I have also considered the option of creating an Endorsement object that is tied to the User, so that a User `has_many` endorsements, each of which would have a category attribute and a body attribute.

Any hints on coding the form for either of the above would be extremely helpful. With both of them I'm not sure how to make a button function as a checkbox (I've tried giving `f.checkbox` the bootstrap `btn btn-default` class but it didn't work).  If (2), can I make that part of the form create objects separate from what's being declared at the top of the form in the `form_for @user` code?

Here is the current code that is creating the buttons and fields:

```
  .form-group.odd
    .row
      .col-sm-12
        = f.label :endorsements, "Job Categories"
        Click the categories that interest you and then explain why you'd be good at that kind of job!
    .row
      - Category.all.each do |cat|
        - if cat.id == 1 || cat.id == 4 || cat.id == 7
          .row
        .col-sm-4
          .btn.btn-default.category_button{:id => "#{cat.name}_button"}= cat.name.capitalize
          = f.text_area :endorsements, rows: '2', id: "#{cat.name}_input", class: "category_input"
```

The above code currently doesn't work because the `endorsements` attribute doesn't actually exist, and I know that there is nothing there to record which category buttons are checked. I think if the `endorsements` attribute existed all this would do is save the text input from the `text_area`s (as an array since there are multiple `text_area`s??).

Answer (score 0):

You can always just style checkboxes to appear as buttons. Then you can have the functionality of a checkbox with the look and feel of a button. Here is a JSFiddle I found that demonstrates the basic idea of this.

http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="ck-button">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>red</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div label input {
   margin-right:100px;
}
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#ck-button {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

#ck-button label {
    float:left;
    width:4.0em;
}

#ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#911;
    color:#fff;
}
```